# De onde vem a expressão "Taquara rachada"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Quando uma pessoa que possui a voz irritante ou estridente, é comum ouvirmos a expressão "Ela tem voz de "taquara rachada".

De onde vem esta terminologia? O que seria uma "taquara rachada"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Taquara**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taquara) é a denominação comum a várias espécies de gramíneas nativas da América do Sul, a maioria com caules ocos e segmentados em gomos, em cujas intersecções se prendem as folhas.

[image]  [[image]][2[![]
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI4k8.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI4k8.jpg)

[**Flávia Neves**](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/origem-expressao-taquara-rachada/) apresenta o seguinte comentário sobre a "taquara",

> - A taquara é também chamada de taboca e taquari. Essas plantas são também usadas na construção de pífaros, **instrumentos de sopro que são melodiosos apenas se forem tocados corretamente e se não estiverem rachados, claro!**

e para "taquara rachada":

> - **Taquara rachada** é uma expressão usada para indicar uma pessoa que tem uma voz tão estridente e desafinada, que chega a ser desagradável e irritante.
> - Que voz irritante! Parece uma taquara rachada!
> - Minha filha cantando parece uma taquara rachada.
> - Já não aguento mais ouvir aquela voz de taquara rachada!
> - Por mais que treinasse, continuava com voz de taquara rachada.

Embora seja um site de humor, a [**Desciclopédia**](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Taquara_Rachada) tem definição semelhante.

> - Taquara é um instrumento musical feito de bambu, tem um lindo som, mas quando quebra ou racha fica com um som horrível e insuportável, por isso quando alguém tem a voz ruim chamamos de taquara rachada. Voz de taquara rachada é comum em  adolescentes* de 13 a 16 anos.

"Em rapazes de 13 a 16 anos quando ocorre a mundança de voz", é provavelmente o que o autor quis dizer.

O instrumento musical taquara tem também outras denominações regionais: pife, pífano, taboca.

> [**O pife brasileiro**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pife_brasileiro), mais conhecido regionalmente como pífano, é uma adaptação nativa, com influência indígena, das flautas populares europeias. Feita de **taboca**   como as flautas indígenas, o pife brasileiro é utilizado pelos caboclos nordestinos para cerimônias religiosas e festas. Outros nomes para o pife são **taboca** e pífaro.
>
> "taboca" - sinônimo de [**"taquara"**](https://www.dicio.com.br/taquara/)

Comment: Na verdade, `taquara` é o bambu para fabricar o instrumento, que é uma flauta de bambu com um som bastante folclórico. O instrumento em si se chama `pífano` (confesso que tive de procurar o nome na Wikipedia).

Comment: 1. A primeira citação devia ligar à página concreta da Desciclopédia, e não à página principal. 2. Não se pode achar uma fonte para a primeira citação? É que segundo eles próprios, "a Desciclopédia é um site de humor debochado e *seu conteúdo não deve ser levado a sério*."

Comment: @ANeves   Sim, deveria, mas erros acontecem. Muchas gracias por la corrección.  :-)

Comment: Esse instrumento, o pífano (ou pífaro, ou pife), é tradicional do nordeste brasileiro. Nos anos 1970, participações da Banda de Pífanos de Caruaru em álbuns de Caetano Veloso e Gilberto Gil, entre outros, tornaram o instrumento um pouco mais conhecido. Uma boa amostra: https://youtu.be/MMOUWcAmxVQ

Comment: @bfavaretto   Não é exatamente o que eu chamaria de som lindo ou agradável.  Mesmo levando em conta o trabalho artesanal realizado em condições precárias.

Comment: **Atenção!** Desciclopédia é um site de humor não é uma base de informações.

Comment: Provavelmente do Brasil

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar um "pitaco" como músico.

Taquaras preparadas como instrumentos musicais, assim como outros instrumentos de sopro (flautas, *sakuhachis*, saxofones, etc.), possuem uma interessante característica que é a de produzir mudanças bruscas de frequência sonora (de sons agudos para graves e vice-versa) conforme a coluna de ar sendo soprada dentro delas é alterada mediante o tapamento ou destapamento dos orifícios responsáveis pela modulação das notas musicais.

Essas mudanças bruscas podem soar desafinadas, especialmente nas mãos de quem não tem tanta prática.

Em especial, quando se deixa mais de um orifício aberto (o que também requer prática para se evitar), o som emitido por múltiplas saídas de ar também tende a ficar desafinado/irritante/estridente, visto que as diferentes notas tocadas simultaneamente são frequentemente espaçadas em intervalos dissonantes (isto é, desagradáveis ao ouvido ou desafinados, que são os de ocorrência mais comum na escala musical, dado um determinado tom musical).

Quem já arriscou praticar um instrumento de sopro ou ouviu alguém praticando (entregando minha idade: Lisa Simpson, é você?) reconhece essas características.

Isso é condizente com a informação retirada da Desciclopédia, de que jovens (mais notadamente os meninos) em fase de mudança de voz podem apresentar "voz de taquara rachada". O efeito é similar, se não completamente análogo, pois a estrutura do trato vocal está se modificando ([1](https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/por-que-a-voz-dos-adolescentes-muda/)).

Aí se pergunta, "por que a expressão popular cita especificamente uma taquara"? Acredito que seja por se tratar de um material para produzir instrumentos mais populares (já citados), com os quais o povo está mais familiarizado, em relação aos eruditos.

Outra possível motivador é que esse fenômeno ocorre em taquarais e bambuzais, conforme os troncos das plantas (chamados de taquaras) vão rachando por processos naturais e o vento passa entre eles, produzindo efeitos sonoros diversos, que podem soar "desafinados" para alguns, o que leva à analogia.